# How do I use an asynchronous delegate?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have a C# windows forms application. One of my buttons has this event :

```
    private void btnNToOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = (int)numUpToThis.Value;
        textResult.Text = Program.asyncCall(value, 2).ToString();
    }
```

And the method it calls is this one :

```
    public delegate int DelegateWithParameters(int numar, int tipAlgoritm);
    public static int asyncCall(int numar, int tipAlgoritm)
    {
        DelegateWithParameters delFoo = new DelegateWithParameters(calcPrim);
        IAsyncResult tag = delFoo.BeginInvoke(numar, tipAlgoritm, null, null);
        while (tag.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        int intResult = delFoo.EndInvoke(tag);
        return intResult;

    }
```

The problem is that it keeps blocking my user interface so I am obviously doing something wrong. How am I supposed to use an asynchronous delegate? Any tips?

Comment: Is `async/await` an option, or you insist on `delegate`?

Comment: Looks like you just need to read through some introductory tutorials on asynchronous programming.  Explaining the entire paradigm of programming is beyond the scope of an approrpatie SO question.

Comment: @IvanStoev , sadly I must use delegate.

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx, especially the **Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes** section

Comment: Thank you so much @IvanStoev , that example helped me better understand what I was doing compared to the other one I was using. It works now, now I have to figure out how to return the result when it's over.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a function? You can have just the synchronous function in a separate place (something like `public static int CalcPrim(int numar, int tipAlgoritm)`, and do the whole async call stuff inside your form,   i.e. inside the callback method, get the result and just set `textResult.Text`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a quick example for this particular case that you can use in general when you need something like this.

First, you can't encapsulate the whole async logic inside the method, because the result cannot be provided with return statement, so provide just the synchronous method

```
static class MyUtils
{
    public static int CalcPrim(int numar, int tipAlgoritm)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then use the following in your form

```
private void btnNToOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = (int)numUpToThis.Value;
    Action<int> processResult = result =>
    {
        // Do whatever you like with the result
        textResult.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    Func<int, int, int> asyncCall = MyUtils.CalcPrim;
    asyncCall.BeginInvoke(value, 2, ar =>
    {
        // This is the callback called when the async call completed
        // First take the result
        int result = asyncCall.EndInvoke(ar);
        // Note that the callback most probably will called on a non UI thread,
        // so make sure to process it on the UI thread
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(processResult, result);
        else
            processResult(result);
    }, null);
}
```

Finally, just for comparison, the equivalent `async/await` code

```
private async void btnNToOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = (int)numUpToThis.Value;
    int result = await Task.Run(() => MyUtils.CalcPrim(value, 2)); 
    textResult.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When you explicitly force a method to be called in a non-UI thread it's not *probably* going to be called in a non-UI thread, it's *certainly* going to be called in a non-UI thread.  Checking whether it's in a non-UI thread is a pointless endevor, and it's all the more pointless considering that invoking would work just fine even if you *were* in the UI thread.  All that said, dumping a bunch of code that the OP won't understand isn't helpful in the long run, it'll just create a cargo-cult programming practice resulting in even greater problems in the future.

Comment: Now this is something I can hold onto whenever I need. Thanks a bunch for helping me.

Comment: The above comment is of course proving the point of my last sentence.

Comment: @Servy Agreed in general. But as you may see, I've put the code after providing OP with the link to the MSDN documentation with similar example, and after he confirmed he have read it, with the intention to help him correlate it to his specific case. Sure I might be wrong, but it reminds me that we all were in a similar situation at some point a long time ago. Of course there was no SO, so we had to figure out all ourselves :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev Pushing someone into a cargo-cult practice is *actively harmful* to them.  It may feel good in the short term, but in the long term it'll only cause bigger and more complex problems as a result of a lack of understanding of core concepts.  If you actually wanted to help them then you *wouldn't* do this.

Comment: @Servy I don't know what "cargo-cult" means, but suppose it's something very bad, so I'll take this into account in the future, thank you.